# set today date with respective format that initialized earlier on jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have already initialized my `jquery datepicker` with the format `dd-M-yyyy`. On some particular event I want to set that datepicket with `today's date` with the respective date format(`dd-M-yyyy`) that already I have set. I tried these codes but none of them are working, help me..

**html**

```
  <input id="SD_WO_DATE" readonly="readonly" type="text">
```

**js**

```
 $("#SD_WO_DATE").datepicker().datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", new Date() );
```

and

```
$("#SD_WO_DATE").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

These are setting date with `mm-dd-yyyy` which I don't want.

Comment: @cerbrus  my situation is different.. plz read question once more.. i want to set today's date with respective format that i initialized earlier reopen plz...

Comment: $('#SD_WO_DATE').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yyyy',changeMonth: true,numberOfMonths: 1 });

Comment: Whoops, looks like I was wrong. Question re-opened.

Comment: @chriz, check my answer. I guess you want to set the todays date in the datepicker format. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LzEAP/4/)**

Use `setDate` property of datepicker with `today` as the value,

```
$('#SD_WO_DATE').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' });

$('button').click(function(){
    $('#SD_WO_DATE').datepicker('setDate', 'today');
});
```

Comment: That's not what the OP's asking.

Comment: @shaunak ur demo working perfectly, and thats what i exactly want, bt y its not working with me? its showing this error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `

Comment: Have you included jQuery UI reference? Post the whole code.

Comment: `$("#SD_WO_DATE").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());` is setting todays date with different format.. but `$('#SD_WO_DATE').datepicker('setDate', 'today');` is showing error

Comment: Can you tell the jquery ui version you are using?

Comment: working for me with 1.10.1 -http://jsfiddle.net/LzEAP/5/. Can you add the code you are using to initialise

Comment: And `dd-M-yyyy` is a wrong format, `dd-M-yy` is the correct format. `yyyy` with add the year 2 times - **23-Jun-20142014**

Comment: `$('#id').datepicker({'label':'Work Order Date','format':'dd-M-yy','autoclose':'true'});` tried that too.. same pblm

Comment: finally. your problem is use  `'dateFormat':'dd-M-yy' ` and not `'format':'dd-M-yy'`.. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/LzEAP/6/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56101/discussion-between-chriz-and-shaunak-d).